# "column does not exist" and "cursor does not exist" for postgres migration (where column clearly exists)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I'm running into some migration problems.

I've tried deleting my last migration file, going into psql and dropping all the new tables and deleting the specific migration row in django_migrations.

But I'm still getting the following errors for the following model:

```
# my model
class Excerpt(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, primary_key=True, editable=False
    )
    body = models.JSONField(default=None)
    slug = ArrayField(
        models.SlugField(max_length=50), unique=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column app_excerpt.slug does not exist
LINE 1: ..."app_excerpt"."chapter_id", "app_excerpt"."body", "app_excer...
                                                             ^      


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", 
line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value     
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column app_excerpt.slug does not exist
LINE 1: ..."app_excerpt"."chapter_id", "app_excerpt"."body", "app_excer...
                                                             ^      


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 643, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 179, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 90, in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 136, in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 90, in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 133, in get_objects
    yield from queryset.iterator()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 353, in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1178, in execute_sql
    cursor.close()
psycopg2.errors.InvalidCursorName: cursor "_django_curs_140256357783360_sync_19" does not exist
```

The strangest part is that I can see the `slug` column in my `app_excerpt` table (and I can even add objects to it via django's shell):

```
# python manage.py shell
from app.models import *
Excerpt.objects.create(body="hi")
Excerpt.objects.create(body="hello", slug=["hello"])
```

```
                  id                  |  body   |  slug   
--------------------------------------+---------+---------
 018086f0-7f92-73c5-0cd0-3205fd36ae6f | "hi"    |
 018086f5-1324-9d3a-43ce-2dd66748f811 | "hello" | {hello}
```

So why is Django unable to see that column?

Answer (score 0):

I was running `python manage.py test --k` which was using the old database. Running `python manage.py test` and recreating a new database fixes it.